# MySql.Data c# .net library which runtime should I use?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, runtime

When adding reference to the [MySQL .NET connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net) I am seeing two entries listed for `MySql.Data`

one with a runtime version of 4.0.30319 and another with a runtime version of 2.0.50727

Which should I reference? does it make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your project targets .NET Framework 4.0, then you'll want to reference the 4.0 version. Otherwise, use the 2.0 version (even if your project targets 3.5).

You can check the version your project targets by right-clicking the project in Visual Studio and selecting *properties*.

Comment: what if my project targets 3.5?

I have dependencies in 3.5 so using 4.0 will not work.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is using the .NET Framework 4.0, the 4.0.30319.
Otherwise, 2.0.50727